# VB.NET Array out of words but only one Index for text in ""

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have no idea how to get an array of words from a string which has words separated by spaces *but* some "words" are delimited by quotes, e.g:

```
Dim blablah As String = "This is some \"nice String\""
```

Should give an array of `["This", "is", "some", "nice String"]`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could regard the string as CSV data where the separator is a space and some fields are enclosed in quotes, which means you can use a [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netcore-3.1) to get the array you are looking for:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim blablah As String = "This is some ""nice String"""
        Dim parts As String()

        Dim strm = New StringReader(blablah)

        Using tfp As New TextFieldParser(strm)
            tfp.Delimiters = {" "}
            tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
            parts = tfp.ReadFields()
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, parts))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> This
> is
> some
> nice String

Other CSV parsers are available if you don't want to use methods from Microsoft.VisualBasic.